# Inter-raters reliability for sentiment analysis lexicon

Tags: psychometrics, agreement-statistics, sentiment-analysis

I have a list of words (more than 2000) which were rated by 4 raters for sentiments like anger (scale from 1 to 5). I run an alpha test on SPSS which gives me a coefficient of >8 which shows a good reliability. My question is, when I conduct a sentiment analysis, would it be right to use the mean of the 4 ratings in order to define a word polarity?